# converting singletone tuple to list

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror

```
a=(3)
b=list(a)
```

typeError: 'int' object is not iterable

but

```
a=[3]
b=tuple(a)
c=list(b)
```

runs without error.

please explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `(3)` is just `3`. `tuple`s are defined by the comma, not the parentheses. If you want a `tuple` with one element, add a comma: `(3,)`.

Answer (score 1):

`(3)` is the number `3` in parentheses and `(3,)` is a tuple:

```
>>> a = (3)
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = (3,)
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

There are no ambiguity with `[3]` so it's a list:

```
>>> a = [3]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
```

The `list` constructor accepts a `tuple` or a `list` but not a `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Define tuple by using comma ,

type(**(3,)**) its of type 'tuple'

type(3) its of type 'int'